# Travelling to US using B1/B2 visa annotation "B1 IN LIEU OF H" to different company

Tags: visas, usa, business-travel

I got a B1/B2 visa sponsored by company X. The visa does not mention the company name but there is a note that says "B1 IN LIEU OF H". I have resigned from company X and joined company Y. Is it possible to travel on this visa for company Y?

Comment: What is your profession?

Comment: It's probably a good idea to ask your US consulate. If you already did, please post what they said.

Comment: Do company Y and your work for company Y meet the criteria for B-1 in lieu of H-1B?  I think you need to ask the consulate whether you can use the visa or need to apply for a new one.  If your travel in the new capacity would be permissible under a normal B-1 visa, I would also advise asking them whether this visa can be used for regular B-1 purposes.  Then, if the consulate says it's okay, you should *also* ask Customs and Border Protection, since the State Department (consulates and embassies) sometimes give incorrect advice, leading to refusal of entry or lesser problems.

Answer (score 1):

As you are no longer with the company for which the visa was issued, you may not be granted entry to the US. This visa functions like any B1 visa but allows certain employers to bring a specific foreign workers based on the B-1 (in lieu of H-1) visas.

Additionally, at the border, you would be unable to provide the same evidence as was presented to the US consulate which considered, and granted, the visa (e.g., purpose of travel, source of pay, host company letter, employer letter).

While the visa may appear to be valid, attempting to use it may have significant, and far-reaching, repercussions.